# What difference it makes when I set python thread as a Daemon

Tags: python, multithreading, daemon

What difference makes it when I set a python thread as a daemon, using `thread.setDaemon(True)`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A daemon thread will not prevent the application from exiting.  The program ends when all non-daemon threads (main thread included) are complete.

So generally, if you're doing something in the background, you might want to set the thread as daemon so you don't have to explicitly have that thread's function return before the app can exit.

For example, if you are writing a GUI application and the user closes the main window, the program should quit.  But if you have non-daemon threads hanging around, it won't.

From the docs: http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon

> Its initial value is inherited from
>   the creating thread; the main thread
>   is not a daemon thread and therefore
>   all threads created in the main thread
>   default to daemon = False.
>
> The entire Python program exits when
>   no alive non-daemon threads are left.

Comment: Ok. Now I have the clear idea about daemon threads. Thanks buddy!

Comment: So what happens to daemon threads when you close the application?

Comment: @Matteo the daemon threads are killed when the program exits.

Comment: ok so going by this definition, should a redis pubsub listener be daemon or not, how do I decide, I want to infinitely listen to redis pubsub messages published from js, i can either set daemon to true and then run a while loop infinitely in the main thread to handle interrupts or I can just call join on the thread in which case also it seems to run infinitely