# what does "(python)program can exit when only daemonic children remain" mean?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, daemon

I've seen this many times,but still don't know the exact meaning.So anyone explains it?
more specifically:

a. I know that if you set `daemon=True` the thread will become a daemon thread.But why do we need a daemon thread?

b. what's the meaning of "can exit"?

Comment: Duplicate look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1412230/1107807 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/15086113/1107807 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/4330156/1107807

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A daemon thread is a process that gets killed when the parent process exits. If you fork a process without setting its `daemon` to `True`, then it will run even if the parent process gets killed/exits. That is why you use `daemon`.

If you could post an example of code that renders that error message we could be more specific...